# Web Editing Versioned Enterprise GDB

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, versioning

I would like to implement a web editing environment where edits are posted to a version of a database (delta tables) not too default.

The idea behind this is so that any edits made through a web app would be looked over and posted to default by a GIS admin.

I have tried to publish a version of the data, but I get a "Feature service requires a registered database" error (code: 00090).

Comment: Google says http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00sq000000m4000000 that should fix your problem with step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @MichaelMiles-Stimson:

> Google says
>   http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00sq000000m4000000
>   that should fix your problem with step-by-step instructions.

That is a link to the Online Help for [00090:  requires a registered database](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00sq000000m4000000):

> You are either publishing a map service with Feature Access (feature
>   service) capability, a WFS capable map service with transaction
>   support (WFS-T), or an Image Service with editing capability enabled,
>   and you have not registered an enterprise geodatabase with the ArcGIS
>   server.